# ADFS 4 can multiple claims provider trusts use same signing certificate

Tags: windows-server-2016, federation, adfs4.0

We would like to federate our ADFS server with 2 partner IDPs. It appears they used the same signing certificate for both test environment federation servers. ADFS 3 therefore won't let me import the 2nd claims provider.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36623048/1529683) comment seems to indicate that ADFS 4 (Windows Server 2016) supports multiple IDPs using the same signing certificate, but I cannot find any supporting documentation that confirms this.

Can someone confirm whether this is supported or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - it is supported for ADFS 4.0.

I have added many Azure AD providers with no problem.

Azure AD uses a common certificate.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mark this as the answer. Thank you.